# Is an Arduino Uno required to send any sort of command to a NodeMCU?

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

I have an Amica ESP8266 NodeMCU I want to send some commands to. I have tried sending some commands like 'AT' and 'AT+CWLAP' but I do not get any sort of output for any command I send to it.

Actually I did not send commands the first time I bought it. I flashed it with a `deauther` program made by spacehuhn then I erased the chip using the `esptool.py --port /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART erase_flash` command multiple times. Then I heard that you can send commands to the NodeMCU using the Serial Monitor using Arduino. So I tried it but no output. So my question is whether I need an Arduino Uno or has the command which I used to erase the factory code of the NodeMCU broken something?

PS. I am a newbie so I don't know much of this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With erase_flash you deleted the AT firmware from flash. You can load it back with esptool or with [Flash Download Tool (Windows only)](http://espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools).

[AT firmware download page](http://espressif.com/en/support/download/at?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14)

Addresses for 4 megabyte flash (more in readme.md of AT firmware):

```
esptool.py -p /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/512+512/user1.1024.new.2.bin 0x3fc000 esp_init_data_default.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x3fe000 blank.bin
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I just needed to edit your command like this `esptool.py -p /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/512+512/user1.1024.new.2.bin 0x3fc000 esp_init_data_default_v08.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x3fe000 blank.bin` Now the commands work fine.

Comment: I have another question. If I flash another program on my nodemcu will the original firmware be overwritten?

Comment: you did that with `deauther` .. do you not learn from your actions?

Comment: @jsotola I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: the AT firmware is nothing special in esp8266. other firmwares exist or you can create your own programs with espressif SDK or with Arduino esp8266 core package

Comment: Like 99.999% of all MCUs the ESP8266 can only hold one program in flash at a time - be that "deuther", the "AT" firmware, or your own custom program. As soon as you install one the last one is removed.